# make <package> implies new Extracting

Tags: linux, embedded, buildroot

I created a Buidroot package with the both following files :

.mk

```
AVM_VERSION = $(BR2_PACKAGE_AVM_TARGET)-V00.00.01
AVM_SITE_METHOD = git
AVM_SITE = ssh://git@myownserver.com/App/AVM.git

AVM_INSTALL_TARGET = YES

define AVM_BUILD_CMDS   
    $(TARGET_CC) $(TARGET_CFLAGS) -o $(@D)/AVM $(@D)/avm.c    
endef

define AVM_INSTALL_STAGING_CMDS 
    $(MAKE) DESTDIR=$(STAGING_DIR) -C $(@D) install
endef

define AVM_INSTALL_TARGET_CMDS
    $(INSTALL) -D -m 0755 $(@D)/AVM $(TARGET_DIR)/usr/bin/avm
endef

$(eval $(generic-package))
```

Config.in

```
config BR2_PACKAGE_AVM
    bool "AVM"
    help
      Application for embedded platform.

config BR2_PACKAGE_AVM_TARGET
    string "AVM package target"
    depends on BR2_PACKAGE_AVM
    help
        Define board
```

I succedded in compiling the package by using the above .mk file. However, because I wanted to modify the source code into output/build I note the following behavior (After removing only .stamp_built) :

```
$ make AVM
>>> AVM v00.00.01 Extracting
...
>>> AVM v00.00.01 Patching
>>> AVM v00.00.01 Configuring
>>> AVM v00.00.01 Building
...
```

I obtain a new Extracting, Patching, Configuring, Building even if no .stamp removed...

What's wrong ?

EDIT :

The problem seems to come from the AVM_VERSION definition. When I exchange `$(BR2_PACKAGE_AVM_TARGET)` by its value I am getting `make: Nothing to do for « AVM ».`

This variable, named $(BR2_PACKAGE_AVM_TARGET), has been defined into the defconfig file associated to the board as `BR2_PACKAGE_AVM_TARGET="AVM2.3"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not `qstrip` `BR2_PACKAGE_AVM_TARGET`, so as far as *make* is concerned, the quotes are part of the version. *make* looks for the file `output/build/AVM-"AVM2.3"-V00.00.01/.stamp_extracted` but that file doesn't exist, so the extraction step will be executed again. Same for all other steps. Note that the download step is skipped because the tarball exists in the dl directory.

To fix, use

```
AVM_VERSION = $(call qstrip, $(BR2_PACKAGE_AVM_TARGET))-V00.00.01
```